# Raspberry Pi Humidity Sensor undefined reference 'pinMode', among others

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, sensors, raspbian

I've been given the task to find a command prompt to pull data from the DHT11 Humidity Sensor installed in a Raspberry Pi (first gen).

I've followed the [directions on this page](http://www.rpiblog.com/2012/11/interfacing-temperature-and-humidity.html), and saved the following code in the /wiringPi directory.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdint.h>  
#define MAX_TIME 85  
#define DHT11PIN 7  
int dht11_val[5]={0,0,0,0,0};  

void dht11_read_val()  
{  
  uint8_t lststate=HIGH;  
  uint8_t counter=0;  
  uint8_t j=0,i;  
  float farenheit;  
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
     dht11_val[i]=0;  
  pinMode(DHT11PIN,OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(DHT11PIN,LOW);  
  delay(18);  
  digitalWrite(DHT11PIN,HIGH);  
  delayMicroseconds(40);  
  pinMode(DHT11PIN,INPUT);  
  for(i=0;i<MAX_TIME;i++)  
  {  
    counter=0;  
    while(digitalRead(DHT11PIN)==lststate){  
      counter++;  
      delayMicroseconds(1);  
      if(counter==255)  
        break;  
    }  
    lststate=digitalRead(DHT11PIN);  
    if(counter==255)  
       break;  
    // top 3 transistions are ignored  
    if((i>=4)&&(i%2==0)){  
      dht11_val[j/8]<<=1;  
      if(counter>16)  
        dht11_val[j/8]|=1;  
      j++;  
    }  
  }  
  // verify cheksum and print the verified data  
  if((j>=40)&&(dht11_val[4]==((dht11_val[0]+dht11_val[1]+dht11_val[2]+dht11_val[3])& 0xFF)))  
  {  
    farenheit=dht11_val[2]*9./5.+32;  
    printf("Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d *C (%.1f *F)\n",dht11_val[0],dht11_val[1],dht11_val[2],dht11_val[3],farenheit);  
  }  
  else  
    printf("Invalid Data!!\n");  
}  

int main(void)  
{  
  printf("Interfacing Temperature and Humidity Sensor (DHT11) With Raspberry Pi\n");  
  if(wiringPiSetup()==-1)  
    exit(1);  
  while(1)  
  {  
     dht11_read_val();  
     delay(3000);  
  }  
  return 0;  
}
```

First...is this Python or just straight Linux commands? If not, what language? (Just curious)

Most importantly, when I compile this code, as per the instructions on the referenced page, I get the following:

undefined reference to 'pinMode'
as well as others like: 'digitalWrite', 'delay', 'delayMicroseconds', 'digitalread', and 'wiringPiSetup'.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Perhaps there's a more straightforward Linux terminal command that would pull the data from the sensor?

Comment: The language of that code is C. you probably can't easily get the data you want straight from a Linux command.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you did the ./build command after cd wiringPi following the steps on your link? I'm wondering whether wiringPi built incorrectly

Comment: No errors with the ./build command, just a note at the end: "To compile programs with wiringPi, you need to add: -lwiringPi to your compile lines.To use Gertboard, MaxDetect, etc. code (the devLib), you need to also add: -lwiringPiDev to your compile lines"

Comment: Your errors are not prefaced by something saying the compiler can't find wiringpi.h ? You might need to post the whole compiler output to diagnose this. It's basically telling you it doesn't know what those functions are, and they should be defined by wiringpi.

Comment: Thank you. I have a senior-level team member on it. Turns out it's not the first time they've had issues with this Raspberry. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem, sounds like it could be fresh linux install (or even fresh R-Pi) time :)

Answer (score 2):

This is **C code**. Compile with fisrt line command and run following line...

```
gcc yourfilename.c -o outputfile -lwiringPi
./outputfile
```

.. and you can see reading humidity and temperature.. (but be careful your dht11 sensor connection)

Please visit this address : http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/dht11-humidity-temperature-sensor-module/

Comment: thank you very much. this worked. but to see the results, you should run the output file in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

At first this is c language, not python. The pinmode function is part of wiring pi. So appearantly wiringpi isn't installed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check with my team members.